# Replace all occurrences of space until the first comma regex?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So basically I have a CSV like:

```
121\sdf\ 34 4333DSssD,23233,TECH,32, ...
```

that first string is the ID but its supposed to have + not spaces. They got trimmed out, so now on each line until the first comma I need to replace any spaces with +.

Was thinking of using regex for this and re.sub (processing using python) but am having trouble only getting the spaces.

Was hoping StackOverflow could help :D

Comment: What if the field in the CSV string has a `,` as part of its data? What if it has an `\n`? RegEx may not be good for that. You have to use a proper CSV file parser before messing with its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without a regex; just partition on the comma and manipulate the left partition

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    left, comma, right = line.partition(',')
    print "%s%s%s" %(left.replace(' ', "+"), comma, right)
```

Comment: If you don't want to assign the delimiter you can get away with: `left, right = line.partition(',')[::2]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution without regular expressions (assuming you have a string with a single line called `line`, this would probably be inside of a `for` loop that is iterating over the file object):

```
pieces = line.split(',', 1)
pieces[0] = pieces[0].replace(' ', '+')
line = ','.join(pieces)
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
import re
line = re.sub(r'^[^,]*', lambda m: m.group(0).replace(' ', '+'), line)
```

Comment: Assuming that every line in the text is a complete CSV row is wrong, and assuming every `,` in the file is a field delimited is wrong too. It can work for simple cases, but this is not how CSV files should be parsed.